# A quotient ring of a polynomial ring over $F$ with infinitely many variables is isomorphic to a polynomial ring in one variable over $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

**The Problem**: Let $F[x, y_1, y_2,\dots]$ be the polynomial ring in the infinite set of variables $x, y_1, y_2, \dots$ over the field $F$, and let $I$ be the ideal $(x-y_1^2, y_1-y_2^2,\dots, y_i-y_{i+1}^2,\dots)$ in this ring. Define $R=F[x, y_1, y_2,\dots]/I$. Denote the image of $y_i$ in $R$ as $x^{1/2^i}$. Let $R_n$ be the subring of $R$ generated by $F$ and $x^{1/2^n}$. Prove that $R_n$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring in one variable over $F$.

**Hint**: First show that the ring $S_n=F[x, y_1,\dots, y_n]/(x-y_1^2, y_1-y_2^2,\dots, y_{n-1}-y_n^2)$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring $F[y_n]$. Then show any polynomial relation $y_n$ satisfies in $R_n$ gives a corresponding relation in $S_N$ for some $N\geq n$.

**Source**: *Abstract Algebra, $\mathit{3^{rd}}$ edition* by Dummit and Foote.

I failed to make use of the first half of the hint, and did not even understand the second half. I failed to come up with an explicit isomorphism from $S_n$ to $F[y_n]$, or a homomorphism from $F[x, y_1,\dots, y_n]$ to $F[y_n]$ with kernel $(x-y_1^2, y_1-y_2^2,\dots, y_{n-1}-y_n^2)$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You meant $y_{n-1}-y_n^2$. Then you are supposed to use that $R[a,b]/(a-b^2) \cong R[b]$ several times.

Comment: @reuns Oops-thanks for pointing that out! That looks like a much more helpful hint-I'll take it!